How to deal with CsrfAuthenticationStrategy unsetting XSRF-TOKEN cookie on authentication?
I'm having issues trying to implement CSRF protection with Spring Boot, Spring Security and Kotlin. I've been testing and learning Spring Security and I've implemented JWT authentication to a test application, but I don't understand how I should deal with CsrfAuthenticationStrategy unsetting the XSRF-TOKEN cookie when the user successfully authenticates to the application with JWT.
The problem occurs in the following way:

I send a POST request to my /api/login endpoint with correct credentials
The application returns the JWT token in the body and the CSRF token in the XSRF-TOKEN header of the response

The backend also sets the XSRF-TOKEN cookie at this point as it should


I send a POST request to my /api/some-endpoint endpoint, which is just a dummy POST endpoint which creates a dummy entity to database (not relevant).

I set the stored JWT-token to the Authorization header and the CSRF-token to the X-XSRF-TOKEN header which the Spring Boot application expects


At this point the POST request is successful, but the application unsets the XSRF-TOKEN cookie (as it should on successful authentication) because of the CsrfAuthenticationStrategy implementation (as mentioned here).
I try to send another POST request to the same /api/some-endpoint endpoint with the same JWT token (in the Authorization header) and the same CSRF token (in the X-XSRF-TOKEN header). This request fails because the XSRF-TOKEN cookie is unset, and Spring Security expects the XSRF-TOKEN cookie and X-XSRF-TOKEN header to match.

And that is the issue. How should I implement CSRF protection here and why does CsrfAuthenticationStrategy unset the CSRF token? How should I get a valid CSRF token between the steps 4 and 5? I am aware that with my authentication strategy CSRF protection is perhaps not necessary, but I'd still like to know where my thinking is wrong.
Here's the relevant part of my custom CustomWebSecurityConfig implementation with the SecurityFilterChain etc:
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig(
    private val userDetailsService: UserDetailsService,
    private val jwtUtil: JwtUtil,
) {
    private fun getCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler(): CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler {
        val csrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler = CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler()
        csrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf")
        return csrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .sessionManagement { sessionManagementCustomizer ->
                sessionManagementCustomizer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            }
            .cors {}
            .csrf {
                it.ignoringRequestMatchers("/register", "/login", "/create-temp-user")
                it.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                it.csrfTokenRequestHandler(getCsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler())
            }
            .authorizeHttpRequests { requests ->
                requests
                    .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**", "/login", "/register", "/create-temp-user")
                    .permitAll()
                requests.anyRequest().authenticated()
            }
            .addFilterBefore(
                JwtAuthenticationFilter(jwtUtil, userDetailsService),
                BasicAuthenticationFilter::class.java
            )
            .addFilterAfter(CsrfCookieFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            .headers { headers ->
                headers.frameOptions { frameOptions ->
                    frameOptions.sameOrigin()
                }
            }

        return http.build()
    }
}

Here's the CsrfCookieFilter mentioned in the filter chain:
class CsrfCookieFilter : OncePerRequestFilter() {
    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        val csrfToken = request.getAttribute(CsrfToken::class.java.name) as CsrfToken
        if (!csrfToken.headerName.isNullOrBlank()) {
            response.setHeader(csrfToken.headerName, csrfToken.token)
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}

Thanks very much for help in advance!

you are trying to learn spring security but i can by looking at your code see that you have been learning it by reading random blogposts on the internet than reading the actual spring docs. JwtAuthenticationFilter this is homemade dangerous security and there is a reason to why this type of filter does not exist in spring security. JWTs should not be handed out to browsers, and is well known within the security community. JWTs should only be used as service to service authorization, and spring security already has built in support for this, so please delete this home made security.

also if you are serious learning spring security then use the tools that are implemented in spring security. Learn how they work, then read their code to understand how they do it. There is a huge chapter on CSRF that explains the difficulties with it, BREACH vulnerabilities, and how different applications need CSRF differently https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/csrf.html

and to add to what you are thinking wrong, since JWTs are not to be handed out to browsers, specifically not in the body so that javascript has access to it (because of XSS-vulnerabilities (any type of security token should always be in a cookie, due to security flags like Secured, SameSite, HttpOnly) you wont be needing CSRF, since CSRF is a browser vulnerability, and jwts are never meant to be in browsers. So they dont go hand in hand.

@Toerktumlare: I've been learning Spring Security through a web course, so not through reading the actual docs indeed. I think documentation is a great reference, but not always the most straightforward way to start learning something new.
I am currently learning OAuth and OIDC etc. as well, but just want to know how filters and authentication work in general. I think implementing a custom JWT solution has helped me a great deal with learning those concepts.

@Toerktumlare and yes like I said, I was aware that CSRF is not necessary when using JWT. But what I was not aware of was that the JWT authentication in fact blocking me from implementing CSRF protection as well, as the user had to be reauthenticated on every request and therefore the CsrfAuthenticationStrategy set the cookie as null on every request as intended. When using a stateful authentication, such as sessions, user is not "reauthenticated" on every request and therefore the CSRF token is not reset on every request. And that's why it works when using sessions, for example.

well i have no idea why you have written a custom JWTFilter, as handing out JWT to browsers in dangerous and there is an entire chapter on JWTs in the spring security docs, and there is a reason to why spring security does not have such a filter. So remove you home made JWT filter

@F4irline did you find an answer to this issue?

The reason the CSRF protection was not working in my case is the authentication implementation itself (JWT). When using a stateless authentication such as JWT, the user has to be "reauthenticated" on every request, so due to CsrfAuthenticationStrategy the CSRF token is always reset as well.
When using a stateful authentication such as a session, the server stores the authentication details in the session itself and does not reauthenticate the user on every request. Because of that, the CSRF token is not reset on every request (as the user is not "reauthenticated") and the initial CSRF is valid until the user logs out or the user has to be reauthenticated (e.g. when the session expires).

I also experienced the same issue, and the problem was resolved after setting the JwtAuthenticationFilter before the ExceptionTranslationFilter.
